# SpringSource Spring MVC Template errors when created

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, springsource

I'm just getting started with SpringSource, so I decided to make a Spring MVC project off the template.

However, as soon as I create the template, I get the following error in pom.xml

```
Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5 () (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources:default-resources:process-resources)

Failure to transfer org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:pom:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:pom:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connection timed out to http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-container-default/1.0-alpha-9-stable-1/plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-9-stable-1.pom
```

I've tried reinstalling SpringSource multiple times, and I still get the same error. I'm using SpringSource 3.1.0 32-bit version on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to update your Maven indexes so that it can download the appropriate library required for the template.

- Go to Window > Preferences > Maven
- Check `Download Repository index updates on startup`
- Restart STS.
- Attempt to pull down the template again.

**Note: It may take some time to download all of the indexes.**

[image]

Comment: Checking the `Update Maven projects on startup box` made it work for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For me deleting the contents in my .m2/repository folder and recreating the project (file-> new->) worked